# Is there a way to use "SHC" to compile shell scripts on OSX?

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, compilation

Does anyone know of a way to compile the shell script C compiler "SHC" for use on OSX for "encrypting" OSX bash scripts?  If not, does anyone know of something similar that would work on the mac?  e.g using XCode to somehow compile it?

I know it isn't completely secure but it's at least one more layer in that scripts can't be opened in text editors and easily understood by a human.
Previously I've used Platypus to compile an "encrypted" app, but this is somewhat cumbersome for the task at hand.

You can use the "make" command to install SHC on Linux, but this obviously doesn't exist on the mac..
Thanks.

Comment: `make` comes with all of the other development tools if you install Xcode and its command line tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use the "make" command to install SHC on Linux, but this obviously doesn't exist on the mac

I don't see why that would be obvious, given that it's not true. `make` comes with the Xcode command line developer tools.

Comment: I know this Question is very outdated. But hust in case someone stumbles across it (like me). Nowadays you can install shc via homebrew. Just do a `brew install shc`